Are there any bugs in the `SubresultantPolynomials` and `SubresultantPolynomialRemainders`?
Try the following code
f = x^10 + y^10 + 1 - (x - 1)^4 (x - y) (y - 1)^5;
g = Expand[f];

SubresultantPolynomials[f, D[f, y], y]; // AbsoluteTiming
SubresultantPolynomialRemainders[f, D[f, y], y]; // AbsoluteTiming

It works successfully, however, the kernel quits after long time of computations if I replace f with g.
SubresultantPolynomials[g, D[g, y], y]; //AbsoluteTiming

SubresultantPolynomialRemainders[g, D[g, y], y]; //AbsoluteTiming

Are there any bugs?

There is a bug in the FLINT based version of the subresultants code. Thank you for pointing it out. The bug is fixed for the next version. To avoid using the code, you can locally set "UseFLINT"->False for the Subresultant* functions, e.g.
In[1]:= SubresultantPolynomialsFixed[args__] :=                                 
   Block[{fl},                                                                  
      WithCleanup[                                                              
         fl="UseFLINT"/.("PolynomialAlgebraOptions"/.                           
               SystemOptions["PolynomialAlgebraOptions"]);                      
         SetSystemOptions["PolynomialAlgebraOptions"->{"UseFLINT"->False}],     
         SubresultantPolynomials[args],                                         
         SetSystemOptions["PolynomialAlgebraOptions"->{"UseFLINT"->fl}]]]       

In[2]:= f = x^10 + y^10 + 1 - (x - 1)^4 (x - y) (y - 1)^5 ;                     
In[3]:= g = Expand[f];                                                          

In[4]:= (p1=SubresultantPolynomials[f,D[f,y],y]);//AbsoluteTiming               
Out[4]= {0.063349, Null}

In[5]:= (p2=SubresultantPolynomialsFixed[g,D[g,y],y]);//AbsoluteTiming          
Out[5]= {0.033463, Null}

In[6]:= p1===p2                                                                 
Out[6]= True

